# backbone.js model.save doesn't set the id

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I've inherited a backbone js based app. I really like backbone and i'm just starting to get my head around it. From my understanding when model.save is called on a new entity it should post that to the server, the server should return the same json but with an id alloted and backbone should persist that id to the model so that further saves result in a PUT with the ID for update.

However, when I call `model.save()` and then try to get the model.id property, it's null.

Is this because I'm not doing it with a call back? So the property hasn't been set yet?

How would I set the success callback? calling `model.save({success: function(){...}})`doesn't work?

here is the actual call:

```
model.save(null, {
    success: function () {
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the error callback too?

Comment: have you verified that the server does indeed get called?

Comment: Did you create your 'model' using Backbone.Model.extend?

Comment: is the idAttribute set?  this is the way to change the default 'id' to be something else (like, say 'entityId')

Comment: can you post the response that your server provides, including the json result and the http header status?

Comment: it was to do with setting silent: true on the save - bit random but worked :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something feels odd about this.  Setting `silent: true` only makes it so none of the events get fired.  Everything else should happen normally.  In other words, don't assume that setting `slient: true` is the right answer here...

I suspect you are actually throwing an exception some place (probably with validation or something like that) and somehow, setting `silent: true` is causing everything to flow through.

I would strongly suggest that you remove this option and check your console or run with the debugger... I suspect you have a bug lurking around there some place.

Some suggestions:  Take a look at the [annotated source](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-28) for the `model.set` function.  It gets called before your `success` callback will get called.  Inside of that function, there are several things that will happen if `silent` is false.  These include [validation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-30), individual [property change](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-33) triggers, and a [global change](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-34) trigger.  I would bet money that either the validation is failing or something that is listening to the changes is throwing an exception.

Comment: OK I'll have a look in the morning and report back :)

Comment: So, what ended up being the problem?

Answer (score 0):

i needed to set the silent: true on the save:

```
    model.save(null, {
        silent: true,
        success: function () {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hmmmm... I suspect this isn't a random fix, but you are covering up a bug in your code by doing this.  Take a look at my response.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, turned out to be because my custom `parse` was failing